# batch file to search all drives for a specific file and delete that file

Tags: windows, batch-file, command-line

I'm trying to make a batch file to find a file (for example Raihan.txt) and delete it or forced delete it(if its running).
In this case I want it to **search all drives including USB drives**.
I actually don't know much about batch coding, I searched it on internet and came up with those line and **problem is I can't search all drives**. I need some help here.

```
@echo off
set file_to_delete=Raihan.txt
set dir_to_look_in=C:\

:: Starting loop
for /f "tokens=1* delims=" %%f in ('dir /s /o /b "%dir_to_look_in%" ^| findstr "%file_to_delete%"') do (
    echo INFO: Deleting: %%f
    del /q "%%f"
)
```

I haven't run it because it's not even complete, one wrong move and **I will be in big trouble**.

Comment: Use the search facility at the top of the page. There are already answered questions whereby the intent was to search all connected drives for a file or directory object. This site is not here to search for you then link those results, neither are we supposed to answer duplicated questions.

Answer (score 0):

Here is one example

```
@echo off
set file_to_delete=Raihan.txt

:: Starting loop to search through all drives
for %%d in (A B C D E F G H I J K L M N O P Q R S T U V W X Y Z) do (
    if exist "%%d:\%file_to_delete%" (
        echo INFO: Deleting: "%%d:\%file_to_delete%"
        del /q "%%d:\%file_to_delete%"
    )
)
```

Here is another

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
set "file_name=Raihan.txt"
for /f "tokens=1-2" %%a in ('fsutil fsinfo drives ^| findstr /r "^[A-Z]:"' ) do (
  if exist "%%a:\%file_name%" (
    echo Deleting "%%a:\%file_name%"
    del "%%a:\%file_name%"
  )
)
```

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
set "file=example.txt"

for %%i in (A B C D E F G H I J K L M N O P Q R S T U V W X Y Z) do (
    if exist "%%i:\" (
        for /f "delims=" %%j in ('dir /s /b "%%i:\%file%"') do (
            set "filepath=%%j"
            del "!filepath!"
            echo !filepath! deleted
        )
    )
)

echo All instances of %file% have been deleted.
pause
endlocal
```